# How can i redirect cart item product to specific page in Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to like once click on cart item product it'll be redirect to custom page. Following image is cart page
[image]

I have tried following script but not work.

```
   add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'redirect_on_add_to_cart' );
function redirect_on_add_to_cart() {
        if ( isset( $_POST['add-to-cart'] ) ) {
            $product_id = (int) apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_product_id', $_POST['add-to-cart'] );

            if($product_id == 322 || $product_id == 320){
                return get_permalink( 30 );
            }       
        }
}
```

Comment: @ShivendraSingh have you clicked on product link ?

Comment: I click on add to cart.

Comment: No, you didn't get my question , I explain clearly that once i click on cart item product link it'll goes to custom page URL. See image

Comment: did you try 'woocommerce_loop_product_link' filter to the change required Product Permalinks on based on product id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this using `woocommerce_cart_item_permalink` filter hook

```
function filter_woocommerce_cart_item_permalink($product_get_permalink_cart_item, $cart_item, $cart_item_key){
  $productId = $cart_item['product_id'];
  $customUrl = get_permalink( get_page_by_path( 'box_select_product' ) );
  $updatLink =add_query_arg( 'product_box_id', $productId, $customUrl );
  return $updatLink; 
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_permalink', 'filter_woocommerce_cart_item_permalink', 10, 3 );
```